# The purpose of msvcp90 and other ms related dlls

Tags: visual-c++, libraries

What is this and what is it purpose. I notice that when i compile my console apps in c++ is dynamically links it. I'm just curious what purpose this file serves and is it exploitable in the sense that if it has to be on every ones machine to run c code , is there some way for Microsoft or some other entity to exploit it for malicious ends.

Comment: I think this is a worthwhile question because if you search the internet for msvcp90 you get *so* much spam.

Comment: That's the very reason I'm asking the question. Everything that Ive tried to find is related to it being missing and nothing discussing its purpose or safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Standard C++ Library for native code, here you can read more about these libraries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: That link only states very general that its necessary to use msvcp90 to run c++ programs made in vs2008. What it doesn't say is what it does.I don't see any other research that spells out the purpose of these files. With a lot of the windows API being exposed it should make you wonder what is in these files that are so necessary .

Comment: It exports the Standard C++ functions you rely on to develop your code

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, you only need it if you are using the Standard C++ Library, which exposes its functionality through msvcp90.dll, if you are using only Win32 API (which exposes its functionality mainly through kernel32.dll, user32.dll and gdi32.dll), you don't need msvcp90.dll